# Statement to change the background color

Tags: java, android

I have a button that is a type Button that is gonna be clicked. When this is clicked, It is changing color to green.

When I click the button it changes color to green, but when I click it again, it should go back to the standard color.

I have 2 drawable files with names checked_list and not_checked_list.
These two are working good.

But when I click the button, the click has happened. And I can't click it again for some reason.

I have a Button field with a public void sendMessage method that is hooked to the buttons onClick. Is it better to just set an onClickEvent for the button in the code instead.

Here is the code I have so far.

```
int checked = 0;
    Button gotIt;
    gotIt = (Button)findViewById(R.id.got_it);

switch(checked) {
    case 0:
        gotIt.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.checked_list);
        checked = 1;
        break;
    case 1:
        gotIt.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.not_checked_list);
        checked = 0;
        break;
}
```

So here I want it to change between these two colors when I click it.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all of the code you posted is inside your onClick method, then checked int is always 0 and will never be 1 because it is set in the first line of the method. Move your checked int outside of this method and it should work. 
Setting click listener dynamically will have same result as setting in XML layout.

```
int checked = 0;
Button gotIt;

void sendMessage(View v) {
gotIt = (Button)findViewById(R.id.got_it);

switch(checked) {
    case 0:
        gotIt.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.checked_list);
        checked = 1;
        break;
    case 1:
        gotIt.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.not_checked_list);
        checked = 0;
        break;
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot. Of course I have to put checked outside the method. Why I didn't think of that is just.. wow . Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to keep track of the last value for `checked`. Right now you are resetting it every time to `0` because it is a local field in your method call. Make `checked` as a class field and it will work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this method

```
//global variables
boolean isChecked = true;
Button gotIt;

//put this in onCreate()
gotIt = (Button)findViewById(R.id.got_it);

gotIt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View v) {
    if(isChecked == true){
        gotIt.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.checked_list);
        isChecked = false;
    }else{
        gotIt.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.not_checked_list);
        isChecked = true;
    }

  }
});
```